# Virtual function not returning derived type with multi-level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a class hierarchy with multiple levels of inheritance.

1. `cloneable` declares a pure virtual member function returning `cloneable *`.
2. `base` derives from `cloneable`, but does not declare any member functions.
3. Finally, `derived` derives from `base` and defines the virtual function, but overrides the return type to `derived *`.

Calling the virtual function via a `base` pointer to `derived` object returns `cloneable *`. I was expecting `base *` because the implementation of the virtual function returns `derived *` which is convertible to `base *`. What is going on here?

If I declare the pure virtual function in `base`, I can finally get `base *` from it, but I do not understand why this declaration is necessary.

Code:

```
struct cloneable
{
  virtual cloneable * clone() = 0;
};

struct base : cloneable 
{
// virtual base * clone() = 0;    // this line resolves the compile error
};

struct derived : base
{
  virtual derived * clone () { return new derived; }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  derived d;
  base * bp = &d;
  base * bbp = bp->clone();  // error: invalid conversion 
                             // from ‘cloneable*’ to ‘base*’      
  return 0;  
}
```

Note: I've deliberately omitted the virtual destructor to shorten the code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly how do you think the compiler should guess that you want a version returning a `base*`, without any declaration?

---

While the above question answers your direct question, I feel that I should also add some advice.

First of all,

- do make the `clone` function `const`, so that it can be called on a `const` object or via an rvalue expression.

I.e.,

```
virtual cloneable* clone() const;
```

Secondly, to create a *clone* of an object,

- return `new T( *this )` (using copy constructor), not `new T` (using default constructor).

And third,

- for safety, for the publicly available `clone` operation return a smart pointer such as a `unique_ptr<MyClass>`, not a raw pointer.

However, with the change of return type to smart pointer, you will no longer benefit directly from the C++ support for **covariant function results**, which is only for raw pointers and references. So one way to do that is to have a non-`public` raw pointer result implementation, which can have covariant result type, and simply a typed `public` wrapper that returns a smart pointer. In effect you're then implementing the covariance for the public interface, yourself, and it can look like this:

```
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr
using namespace std;

class Base
{
private:
    virtual Base* virtualClone() const
    {
        return new Base( *this );
    }

public:
    unique_ptr< Base > clone() const
    {
        return unique_ptr< Base >( virtualClone() );
    }
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
private:
    virtual Derived* virtualClone() const
    {
        return new Derived( *this );
    }

public:
    unique_ptr< Derived > clone() const
    {
        return unique_ptr< Derived >( virtualClone() );
    }
};

int main()
{
  Derived d;
  Base* bp = &d;
  unique_ptr< Base > bbp = bp->clone();
}
```

Comment: You are right. I thought that the compiler would implicitly declare a pure virtual function in `base`, but even if it did that it would probably not override the return type. So the declaration is necessary. Your three points are valid: I need to add const, but I do a proper clone in the "production" code. I am still looking at the example code for returning unique_ptr. Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this that supports smart pointers. It really sucks that there isn't a way to benefit from covariant typing with smart pointers, and instead you need to have this boilerplate code duplicated everywhere.... C++ is really showing its age here.